# CENTOS 7.2 + installing docker on OS with XFS file system

Tags: centos, filesystems, docker, redhat-enterprise-linux, xfs

We have 12 machines with CentOS 7 servers ( VM servers ) where the root file system is XFS (created with `ftype=0`,  default CentOS setting at the time the system was installed).

And we want to install on each VM server docker service

Unfortunately, the Docker overlay2 storage driver requires that file system to have been created with `ftype=1`:

One option to change the ftype to 1 is to do the following steps

1. Boot into CentOS-7-x86_64-LiveGNOME-1804.iso.
2. Open a terminal and sudo -s.
3. Scan for LVM volumes: vgscan
4. Change into the appropriate volume group (centos in my case): vgchange -ay centos
5. Scan for the logical volumes in that group: lvscan
6. Create a mount point for the root FS: mkdir /mnt/root
7. Mount the logical volume corresponding to the root FS: mount /dev/centos/root /mnt/root
8. Dump to remote host: xfsdump -J - /mnt/root | ssh  'cat >/data/rootfs.dump'
9. Unmount the root FS: umount /mnt/root
10. Recreate the root FS: mkfs.xfs -f -n ftype=1 /dev/centos/root
11. Mount the recreated root FS: mount /dev/centos/root /mnt/root
12. Restore from remote host: ssh  'cat /data/rootfs.dump' | xfsrestore -J - /mnt/root
13. Reboot. Everything should be as it was before, except xfs_info / should now show ftype=1.

But we want to know what the other alternative for steps 1-13 , because steps 1-13 required **downtime** on the servers

Is any other approach to change the `ftype` to 1 ?

For example maybe by adding additional disk to the OS and create xfs file system with `ftype=1`  , and allocate the docker to run on this disk?